# How to enable/disable bluetooth in a service class in android?

Tags: android, service, permissions, bluetooth

I want to enable disable bluetooth  from my service class in android i am using the following code

```
     BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();    
                    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                        mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
                    }else{ 
                        mBluetoothAdapter.disable(); 
                    }
```

But it is not working so how can i enable/disable bluetooth from my service class and which permissions i need

Comment: check http://androiddesk.wordpress.com/tag/enabling-and-disabling-bluetooth-in-android/

Comment: checked but didnt solved my problem

Comment: Are you getting any error? Try using debugger or `Log` messages to see the control flow. You might notice the cause of it.

Comment: there is no error it is just not working....

Answer (score 0):

Using Bluetooth Permission :

Have you used this permission in your manifest file :
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"

Comment: yes i have bluetooth and bluetooth admin permissions in the menifest